# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, maven

Ao tentar iniciar minha aplicação JSF meu retorna esse erro :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
           <version>3.0.1</version>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>  
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>  
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>  
        <version>1.2</version>  
      </dependency>  

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.bootsfaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootsfaces</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Verifique se os jars do que estão no seu pom também se encontram na pasta lib do projeto. Senão estiverem faça o seguinte: 
**Properties" --> "Deployment Assembly", adicione "Java Build Path Entries -> Maven Dependencies"**

Após de um clean e install no seu projeto, limpe o diretório de deploy do seu servidor. Se for tomcat, clique com o lado direito do mouse em cima do ícone e vá em "clean". Em seguida suba o servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez esteja faltando a declaração do tipo do packaging do seu projeto no seu "pom.xml".

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Após adicionar, atualize seu projeto Maven (Update Maven Project).

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).