# Erro ao ativar Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

Tomcat esta instalado no windows como serviço e vinculado no 
eclipse conforme imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Log de Erros:

```
jul 21, 2017 4:12:15 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
ADVERTÊNCIA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:teste1' did not find a matching property.
jul 21, 2017 4:12:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.16
jul 21, 2017 4:12:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server built:          Jun 21 2017 17:01:09 UTC
jul 21, 2017 4:12:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server number:         8.5.16.0
jul 21, 2017 4:12:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: OS Name:               Windows 7
jul 21, 2017 4:12:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: OS Version:            6.1
jul 21, 2017 4:12:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Architecture:          amd64
jul 21, 2017 4:12:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121
jul 21, 2017 4:12:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Version:           1.8.0_121-b13
jul 21, 2017 4:12:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
jul 21, 2017 4:12:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
jul 21, 2017 4:12:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
jul 21, 2017 4:12:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
jul 21, 2017 4:12:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
jul 21, 2017 4:12:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\wtpwebapps
jul 21, 2017 4:12:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\endorsed
jul 21, 2017 4:12:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
jul 21, 2017 4:12:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMAÇÕES: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\totvs\CorporeRM\API;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\cpp\bin\Intel64;C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeGear\RAD Studio\5.0\bin;C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\5.0\Bpl;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress.VCL\Library\Delphi11;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Users\osm\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin;C:\totvs\CorporeRM\API;.]
jul 21, 2017 4:12:16 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
jul 21, 2017 4:12:16 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMAÇÕES: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
jul 21, 2017 4:12:16 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
jul 21, 2017 4:12:16 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMAÇÕES: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
jul 21, 2017 4:12:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMAÇÕES: Initialization processed in 889 ms
jul 21, 2017 4:12:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting service [Catalina]
jul 21, 2017 4:12:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.16
jul 21, 2017 4:12:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/teste1]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/teste1]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet
    at com.sun.faces.config.FacesInitializer.<clinit>(FacesInitializer.java:105)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.loadServices(WebappServiceLoader.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.load(WebappServiceLoader.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1622)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1135)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:775)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5105)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    ... 18 more

jul 21, 2017 4:12:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:656)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

jul 21, 2017 4:12:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
GRAVE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:656)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

jul 21, 2017 4:12:16 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFORMAÇÕES: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
jul 21, 2017 4:12:16 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFORMAÇÕES: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
jul 21, 2017 4:12:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Stopping service [Catalina]
jul 21, 2017 4:12:16 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFORMAÇÕES: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
jul 21, 2017 4:12:16 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFORMAÇÕES: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

Comment: Em `details>>` qual é a mensagem exibida? poderia [edit] a pergunta e adicioanar ela.

Comment: Parece que não deu muito certo, @rray

Comment: Só com isso não tem como dizer algo que resolva o problema. vc instalou o tomcat? foi no linux ou no windows? é um serviço? como configurou o servidor no eclispe? chegou a olhar no console do eclipse ou no log de erros do tomcat?

Comment: Melhor `details` de uma mensagem de erro

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.2</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

Comment: Relacionada ou dup: [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90272/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-javax-faces-webapp-facesservlet)